# What was the "Fuel" for Tangent Superman [Harvey Dent's] powers?

Tags: dc, superman, harvey-dent

The Tangent Superman is a high level psychic and even reality warper from a different reality (Earth 9). However, he started off as a normal *human,* that earth's Harvey Dent, who got his powers from prenatal gene manipulation using an experimental "Miracle solution" which the US government unscrupulously released into a small town prior to his conception.

[image]

Harvey would grow up to be a police officer, seeking to help people, and this line of work would lead to his powers emerging. Whereas first he was thought to be a high level psychic with powers that *far* surpassed the likes of Manchester Black, he also showed everything from being able to enhance his own physical abilities to technopathy to adaptive evolution to *sensing beings in other dimensions!* Going up against Clark Kent Superman, he wasn't quite a *physical* match for him....however, with his advanced brain, he was able to psychically *override* even  **Clark's** nervous system control, shutting down his lungs for a bit.

Even doing something like *That* to Clark takes **massive** amounts of power.... but other than, "his mind", no real *power source* is given for his abilities; no heavy amounts of food, no use of the forces around him, no extra-dimensional energy.... dude doesn't even absorb sunlight. Granted, like Charles Xavier his mind *itself* would be a primary weapon, and would generate its own energy or pull power from the psychic plains....but that doesn't explain some of his other, physical and temporal abilities.

Is there any information or even theories on what may be fueling his capacities?